# How can I return 200 when I get 404 by editing .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes, http-status-code-200

I've a .htaccess file and an index.html file in root directory of a domain. I've codes below in this .htaccess file:

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])?$ /index.html [L]
```

I hope users will see the contents in index.html when they access to a directory URL no matter this directory URL has trailing slash or not. So I have code above.

But I have a problem. When I access to a directory which doesn't exists. I get 404. This is not what I want. I hope users will always forever get 200 and see contents in index.html when they access to a directory URL. How can I resolve this problem by editing codes above in .htaccess file?

BTW. Please don't redirect users to the index.html file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a custom 404 page and call it for example "404page.php". Make sure that this page sends a 200 status before sending any other content to the browser by putting this at the top:

```
<?php
header("Status: 200 OK");
?>
```

Then enter `ErrorDocument 404 /404page.php` in your htaccess.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Gaia. It works. :-) But it would be a better solution if I can achieve this by only editing the .htaccess file. I mean don't edit the .php file.

Comment: This question is about `.htaccess` file. Not about returning `404` in PHP.